# MongoDB concept direct access to files or access imported data (accessing RAW data)

Tags: mongodb, data-mining, raw-data, database

I want to try to use MongoDB to access large millions of rows of RAW data (multiple different files)

If I use MySQL, I have to import/convert those RAW data to MySQL tables which is really time consuming.

My questions is that, If I use MongoDB, do I have to import/convert those RAW data to MongoDB database collections?
If I have to do this, what is the advantage of using MongoDB? time-saving?

Is it possible to access the RAW data directly using MongoDB?

I have a friend who use MongoDB to access apache log files (access_log). But I don't know if he convert the data in access_log files to MongoDB or directly access the accesss_log files.

I'm still confused with the concept of MongoDB

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is database, so really it's designed to store *data*, not "raw files" ...

To access your files "directly" yes, I suppose you would need to *import* the files into MongoDB (however that's pretty easy.)

**GridFS**

MongoDB has a file-system of sorts called [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) "a specification for storing large files in MongoDB."

By default, MongoDB has a 4mb limit on documents (how you store data in MongoDB) so GridFS is designed to store larger files.

For example, with the [command line tools](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Tools) it's just one line to import a file:

```
$ ./mongofiles put myfile.txt
```

Or you could use one of [many available drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS#GridFS-LanguageSupport) that support GridFS.

**Or Don't Store the Files ...**

You could of course, just store the file locations (filename & path) in any DB really, if you don't want to import the files.

However, it sounds like your friend isn't storing the apache log **files** in MongoDB but rather storing the logs (**data**) themselves in MongoDB ...

**More Info**

You can learn more about how to use GridFS here: http://learnmongo.com/posts/getting-started-with-mongodb-gridfs/